# Collapsible side bar in lightning console application

Tags: lightning-experience

Can collapsible side bar possible in lightning console app. I know its possible in salesforce classic and I need the same kind of setup in lightning console app.

[image]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot which sidebar are you talking? I am confused with side bar present on home page or list view side bar in console?

Comment: I have added the screenshot let me know if it is clear now.It is on Case detail view having knowledge as sidebar which is collapsible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Salesforce Classic, this feature is called the Knowledge One
>   sidebar component. In Lightning Experience, use Lightning App Builder
>   to add the Knowledge component to the case page.

What Knowledge component does in Lightning?

> This component helps console users quickly find relevant Knowledge
>   articles for their cases and perform basic actions, such as attaching
>   an article to a case. This component provides similar functionality to
>   the Knowledge Sidebar used in Salesforce Classic consoles. To use this
>   component, Lightning Knowledge must be enabled in your org.

Refer the image below:-

[image]

> Lightning Knowledge is different from Knowledge in Salesforce Classic.
>   [Learn more.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_compare_classic_lightning.htm&type=5)

So for Your answer, In Lightning, You will not have knowledge as collapsible but it is there. You can put it anywhere you want on the page using Lightning App Builder. I would suggest to play with **accordin** available in Lightning App Builder and put Knowledge component inside that according to yourself.

For your reference:- [What Features Are Available in Lightning Console Apps?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_feature_parity.htm&type=5) and [Customize Your Lightning Console Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_custom_pages.htm&type=5)

You will be also interested to know this:-

> Lightning console apps allow users to work quickly by opening multiple
>   records and related records on one screen. Now users can work even
>   more quickly with Lightning console split view, a collapsible pane
>   that keeps the list views you need close at hand.

Refer here:- [Keep Everything at Hand with Lightning Console Split View](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_general_lightning_console_split_view.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the details. I understood.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on ✔️in the left side of my answer as it helps you.